# WPF, VB.net, xaml change image visibility on slider value change

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Hi newbie here trying to change image visibility on slider value change I have tried three ways no luck

1. using vb.net so

```
Private Sub SLIDERA_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double)) Handles SLIDERA.ValueChanged


       If SLIDERA.Value = 0 Then

           imageOFF.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
           imageON.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
       End If
       If SLIDERA.Value = 0.5 Then
           imageOFF.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
           imageON.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
       End If
       If SLIDERA.Value = 1 Then
           imageOFF.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
           imageON.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
       End If
   End Sub
```

if I do this the form will not even launch

2. xaml using datatriger

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style x:Key ="imageONstyle" TargetType="Image">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SILDERA, Path=Value}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key ="imageOffstyle" TargetType="Image">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SILDERA, Path=Value}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>


</Window.Resources>

 <Slider x:Name="SLIDERA"   Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" Margin="191,286,67,403" TickFrequency="0.5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"  SmallChange="0.5" LargeChange="0.5" Width="50" Height="16" ValueChanged="SLIDERA_ValueChanged"/>


        <Image  x:Name="imageON" Style="{StaticResource imageONstyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="241,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21" Source="ButtonResources/LIGHTBULBON.png"/>

        <Image  x:Name="imageOFF" Style="{StaticResource imageOffstyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="174,283,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" Source="ButtonResources/LIGHTBULBOFF.png" />
```

but does nothing

3. Is using a converter no luck either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPF and StackOverflow.

#2 is your most correct approach. Best practice is to handle UI changes like this entirely in XAML if possible, with little to no code-behind. This helps keep the logic of how the app works separate from how it looks.

The only problem I see is that your `Slider` is named `SLIDERA`, but in your `Style` you have `SILDERA`- a misspelling. Fixing that should solve things- just make sure you don't try approaches 1 and 2 at the same time.

---

Separately, I would also like to give you some advice: Don't place your elements using `Margin`. `Margin` is for providing some space between elements, not for giving them an explicit position. Instead, learn to use WPF's various [panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview), such as `Grid` and `StackPanel`.

Comment: ahhh crap works now thanks. I am always typing names incorrectly and thanks for the advice!

Comment: You'll learn to watch for that kind of thing with practice. For now, if this solved your problem, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @User1234 When you debug your application, keep an eye on the messages in the Output tab in Visual Studio.  WPF will issue binding errors there, which can help with finding mismatched typos in names.